# relation between potential energy, kinetic energy and sound energy of water

Tags: energy, waves

When water flows its PE gets converted into KE so what causes its   KE to get converted into sound energy and what the difference will occur in its  sound if it is provided with a parallel surface?

Comment: Well, in the field of aeroacoustics that's well covered by Lighthill's and Curle's theories. I think in the water it is basically the same, but I have never worked with this formalism in liquids. If you are sure about the homentropic character of the water flow, the formulation might be the same.

Answer (score 1):

"Sound energy" must mean the vibration of the air (or other medium in contact with your eardrum).

If water molecules collide with each other and with air, then there is a transfer of vibrational kinetic energy. Vibrations in air propagate to your ear as a pressure wave.

For your second question, the more disturbance of the water flow and the more turbulent the flow, the more colliding particles, so to speak.

Comment: When water molecules collide they can produce other form of energy too so why only sound energy??

Comment: @aish I never said "only". Heat, displacements, vibrations,... There is much energy to convert to

Comment: Ok I got  it :-)

Comment: I strongly disagree with "Sound energy must mean vibration of the air". Sound could be mechanical wave in the water as well.

Comment: @VictorPira I don't follow - you don't "hear" metallic vibrations, you "hear" air molecular vibrations so to say. A vibration is per definition not *sound* before it reaches your ear, which I here assume can only happen through air. (Unless you need a long coord into your ear touching your ear drum.)

Comment: It's of course impossible to hear e.g. the earthquake, but if you swim under water and water reaches to your ear drum, you can of course hear sounds propagating just in the water, without any gas medium.

Comment: @VictorPira I see your point. I am assuming that water never reaches the ear drum, though. But *if* that was the case, then water would be the medium. I have made the edit. Thank you.